# How to list files created since 5:00PM yesterday?

Tags: powershell

Having trouble getting this command to work.  I'm attempting to see all files with a specific string in the name created since exactly 5:00PM yesterday, no matter what time I run the script today.  Below is what I have so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$today = (get-date).dayofyear
$string = "blah"
$filepath = "C:\files"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath | where { $_.CreationTime.dayofyear -eq (($today)-1) } -and { $_.CreationTime.hour -ge 17 | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and ( $_.Name -like "*$string*"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get just the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` value (which gives you today at 0:00:00) and subtract 7 hours from that to get yesterday at 5 pm.

```
$cutoff = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(-7)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath | Where-Object {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
  $_.CreationTime -ge $cutoff -and
  $_.Name -like "*$string*"
}
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can replace the condition `-not $_.PSIsContainer` by calling `Get-ChildItem` with the parameter `-File`.